# Append Linq var row to dataTable c#

Tags: c#

I have used Linq to get rows from dataTable and trying to reorder rows in new dataTable data using the following code:

```
var filtered = table.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("STATION__TO").Contains(temp.Name));
data = filtered.CopyToDataTable();
```

Problem I am facing is that whenever I `CopyToDataTable` it overwrites old rows whereas I want to append rows in dataTable data.

Please guide me how I can use `var filtered` to add rows in dataTable without overwriting old rows.

Comment: Try: `filtered.CopyToDataTable(data, LoadOption.Upsert);` instead of your second line. See the other [LoadOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.loadoption?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.LoadOption);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) members.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [DataTable.Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge?view=netframework-4.6.2) method for combining two datatables.

Comment: I don't want to merge to DATATABLES, I want to re order rows depending on some conditions. All I want is a method of writing rows in datatable without overwriting previous rows. Can you help with that ?